# How can i make VS TEST_CLASS(SomeTestClassName) friend

Tags: c++

How can i make VS TEST_CLASS(SomeTestClassName) friend of class that i am testing?
I am new at c++ and can't find any info on net.
If am  simple add

```
friend class SomeTestClassName;
```

to the header of class that is tested - that doesn't works.

Added example:

```
#include "..\CoreTests\ChallengeManagerTests.cpp" //Circular reference? But forward declaration don't works

class ChallengeManager
{
private:
 void PrivateMethod();
public:
 void PublicMethod();
 friend class CoreTests::ChallengeManagerTests; // Compiler can't find ChallengeManagerTests in CoreTests namespace. Forward declaration give class redefinition error.
}

//ChallengeManagerTests:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "..\Core\ChallengeManager.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using namespace Brans;
namespace CoreTests
{
    TEST_CLASS(ChallengeManagerTests)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(RandomInputs)
        {
            Brans::ChallengeManager cm;
            cm. // here i got is not accessible error for private members 

        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Generally, I try to avoid accessing any private members or functions in unit tests because I view them as implementation details that can change. I use unit tests to test the public interface of the class.

Comment: I agree with you. I have 10 classes which i am tested only with public member but this class is and exception: 1) It is generates questions 2)After that, it generated correct answers 3)It testing entities and leaves  only best of the best.. i don't think it will be good to create 3 classes with public access to array, but still i need to test any stage

Comment: Check the definition of the `TEST_CLASS` macro. It might perform some name mangling so the final class name is different from what you give to that macro.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the previous question that you deleted, your testclass name is defined inside a namespace, so you need to provide this same namespace in your friend declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a forward declaration of the test class before you class class ChallengeManager definition as below:

```
class CoreTests::ChallengeManagerTests;
```